# Replace All JFrame Icons Globally

Tags: java, swing, icons, jframe, global

I can replace any given JFrame icon in Swing with a call to JFrame.setIconImage(). However, I have an existing application that pops up lots of JOptionPanes and other JFrames/dialogs, and rather than track them all down I'm wondering if there is a way to switch these over to my custom icon all in one place? Also, in some instances (ProgressMonitor, for example) I don't have access to the actual JFrame to fiddle with.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the `JFrames` you created on a `List`. Then, you can use a loop to get every frame on this list, and apply the icon.